# first-child not functioning when added styling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work my `first-child` li and push the text up a little more, but it's not working. The `last-child` works, but the first child doesn't.

```css
.latest-posts li:first-child { 
    padding-top: -5px;
}
.latest-posts li:last-child { 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 12px; 
    border: 0; 
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```css
.recent-posts-box ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.recent-posts-box .entry {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px 0 0 0;
  float:left;
}
.latest-posts li {
  height:35px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  display:block;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  clear:both;
}
.latest-posts .entry li:first-child {     
  background: blue;
}
.latest-posts li:last-child { 
  margin-bottom: 0; 
  padding-bottom: 12px; 
  border: 0; 
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.latest-posts li:last-child img {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.recent-posts-box img {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.recent-posts-box .entry .date {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.latest-posts li:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px; 
}
.latest-posts a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #423338;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.latest-posts a:hover {
  border-color: #423338;
}
.recent-posts-box .link {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.recent-posts-box .link a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #423338;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.recent-posts-box .link a:hover {
  border-color: #423338;
}
```

```html
<div class="recent-posts-box">
  <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
  <div class="latest-posts-container">
    <ul class="latest-posts">
      <li>
        <img alt="img" />
        <div class="entry">
          Entry 1
          <span class="date">Date 1</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img alt="img" />
        <div class="entry">
          Entry 2
          <span class="date">Date 2</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <li class="link"><a href="/articles">More Articles..</a></li>
</div>
```

Preview:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the first-child aligning is off (as in pushed down a bit), I want to bring it up a bit, but I tried the `li:first-child` and it just doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `padding` can't be negative.

Comment: You can't have negative padding values. Try a negative margin, though even that might not work.

Comment: Please provide the resulting html (without php) and all the css that affects that html. Maybe you could fix it using `vertical-align` instead of using margins or padding, but I can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: @kris I think your problem is caused by `.recent-posts-box .entry {padding: 8px 0 0;}`. Try deleting that.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I saw your code and I think That the result that you wanted to see is what you will see in the code modified by me:

edit this part of code :

```
.recent-posts-box .entry {
 display: block;   /* here without padding:8px 0 0 0; */
 width: 200px;
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has img with float as left and class named .entry which is also in float. And you did not apply clear both before closing the div. Therefore, it does not apply.

**Solution 1:**

```
<li>
        <img alt="img">
        <div class="entry">
          Entry 1
          <span class="date">Date 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
      </li>
```

**Solution 2:**
    .latest-posts li:after{ content:""; display:block; clear:both; height:0px;}

Try this, if not solved i will help you out more.